# What boot parameters do I use for a RPC server?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

So we use the following for Litecoin

```
daemon=1
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
rpcuser=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
rpcpassword=xxxxxxxxxxxx
rpcport=9339
```

What would be the equivalent boot parameters for a fresh node running `geth`?

Comment: geth --help|grep rpc

Comment: RPC in Ethereum does not have `rpcuser` or `rpcpassword`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Just look for geth --help and you'll get the list of commands. Sorry, don't have a machine to check them now. :)

```
"C:\Program Files\Geth\geth.exe" --networkid 2301 --datadir
"D:\TestEth\node1" --identity "node1" --port 5001 --ipcpath
"node1.ipc" --rpc --rpcport 7001 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi
"admin,personal,eth,web3" --nodiscover
```